# JSF dataTable with thousands of checkboxes

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I have a dataTable on JSF that has the following column:

```html
<ice:column style="width:25px;">   
    <ice:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{historyBean.checked[mapEntry2.id]}" partialSubmit="true" id="playlist-select" style="width:25px;"> 
    </ice:selectBooleanCheckbox> 
</ice:column>
```

As you can see it's formed by checkboxes that are bound to an map where keys are ids and values are booleans.

It all works well pretty good. But sometimes the dataTable can have as many as a few thousand rows, and then, when a user checks or unchecks one of the checkboxes, the partialSubmit starts to get sluggish.

What I want, at the end of the day, is to perform an operation on the server on the data of each selected row. So far I'm using the partialSubmit and a map on the server to store the Ids of the selected data.

How can I make the check/uncheck operation be reflected faster on the server? Any clues?

Thank you.

Comment: Do not use an ajax operation, instead a javascript. You would get better help if you explain your functional requirement.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Can you ellaborate a bit on your answer? How do I get the selected values on the server after the user presses a button, for instance? Thanks.

Comment: Based on your last edit, if you really need to do a partial submit on every check/uncheck box, at least you could define the components to process (I'm not aware if IceFaces let's you do that, I know that RichFaces and Primefaces do with their respective `<prefix:ajax>` component).

Comment: Filtering/pagination (like Google does) would be the answer. Presenting 1000 rows at once is inhuman and webbrowsers (especially the one from a company in Redmond) don't like it either.

Comment: @BalusC Please, create an answer with that idea.. That is the logical answer.